# Ajax call to retrieve partial view return 404

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following HTML code in my page model

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" id="tableToChange">
        @Html.Partial("DeliveryDetails")
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following Ajax call which returns an 404 error when clicking on the load button.

```
$(function () {
    $('#load').on('click', function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetDeliveryDetails", "DeliveryController", null)',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#tableToChange').html(data);
                console.log("Success call");
            }
        });
        console.log("Success click");
    });
});
```

The URL seems fine as it returns the following path: 'DeliveryController/GetDeliveryDetails'.
Probably worth noting that the following address doesn't return anything as well:

```
https://localhost:5001/Customer/DeliveryController/GetDeliveryDetails
```

The DeliveryController is as follows:

```
public ActionResult GetDeliveryDetails()
    {

        Debug.WriteLine("Called the controller!");

        return View("DeliveryDetailsView");
    }
```

and is located in the same folder as the main page model (Customer/Delivery.cshtml)

Comment: What is the HTTP verb of the action method GetDeliveryDetails? I assume it is GET because of the convention (unless you have overridden it by placing the HttpPost attribute), but the property 'type' of the ajax's method config object is 'POST'. The routing middleware can't find an action method that matches your request probably.

Comment: You should also change this code: '@Url.Action("GetDeliveryDetails", "DeliveryController", null)' with this one: '@Url.Action("GetDeliveryDetails", "Delivery", null)'. By default, for the controller parameter, the method Action will remove the word 'controller'. So, the endpoint will be: https://localhost:5001/Customer/Delivery/GetDeliveryDetails. This is the call that you need to call that action method.

Comment: @claudiom248 yep, sorry for the POST, GET wasn't working and I was trying everything. After modifying the Url.Action() I'm getting a 500 error.

Comment: Ok, what is the exception message? Could you post more specific information about the error itself?

Comment: @claudiom248 I have found the issue. The 500 error came from not finding the _Layout.cs in my Layouts folder. I have no idea why as it's definately there. After specifying the path of the Layout in the DeliveryDetailsView I don't have the error any more. Thank you for your assistance.